# Inserting record in db mule esb using file endpoint

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I have one query regarding inserting record in database using file endpoint.
I want to insert json type record in db. I create json file and all those file data i inserted into database. My query is i can insert all those data in database successfully but that is continuously inserted data and error occurred Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
How can i solve this error?I don't want to insert data recursively.How can i do this only once?
I used following flow

```
**File->Json to Object->Splitter->Database**
```

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an **Idempotent Message Filter** (after the Splitter) to ensure that duplicate entries are discarded. If you json representation has an unique identifier, use the **Idempotent Message Filter**

```
<idempotent-message-filter idExpression="#[entry.id]">
    <simple-text-file-store directory="./idempotent"/>
 </idempotent-message-filter>
```

Otherwise, use the **Idempotent Secure Hash Message Filter** (which will filter messages based on their hash value)

```
<idempotent-secure-hash-filter messageDigestAlgorithm="SHA26">
    <simple-text-file-store directory="./idempotent"/>
</idempotent-secure-hash-message-filter>
```

Please check the following [reference](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Routing+Message+Processors#RoutingMessageProcessors-IdempotentMessageFilter) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can solve it. but i want to stop my execution. It still continue..How can i solve this?

Comment: Taking into account your info, the problem is that you are processing the same file several times. If you update the database from different files, use the filter before the splitter against the filename or its hash (this will discard the files already processed). If you use the same file (updating it with new content), then you have to use the solution in this answer.

Comment: can you please give me example?which filter i have to use and how can i know file already processed??

Comment: Another solution is to configure the file endpoint to move or rename (to fail the name pattern) the processed files. This way you ensure that already processed files do not "enter" in the endpoint again.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would try to avoid an idempotent filter with a simple message store as it will prevent potential ulterior updates of the data in the DB.

If your DBMS suports it I would try using an UPSERT mechanism that will effectively render your query idempotent. This could be done with this in [postgresql](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/UPSERT) and with this in [mysql](http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2013/09/30/how-to-do-an-upsert-in-mysql/).

Answer (score 0):

You can check the duplicates easily using **.ack**  queries in Mule...

**.ack** are the query that runs immediate after normal query automatically ...

You need to create .ack query which will run immediately after your insert query and will check the rows already inserted and set the flag...

Check here how to do it with **.ack** query :- 
http://training.middlewareschool.com/mule/database-transport/
and here :- 
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/JDBC+Transport+Reference#JDBCTransportReference-Acknowledgment

Comment: Thanks for reply.Is there any other way ? because I don't want to create an extra column(as flag) in my database